# Get text from string with non-alphanumerical characters in Python

Tags: python

I have this string and I cannot create the right regular expression to simply obtain just the name of the team.

Original string: `'Atlanta Hawks (15)'`

Desired string: `'Atlanta Hawks'`

I have been able to obtain 'Atlanta Hawks ' by using '[A-Za-z0-9\s]*(?<=\s\B)' but I believe there should be another more efficient approach where I get rid of the last white space?

Comment: how about .strip()

Comment: Is there a format followed by all names? Like number will only be at the end? And number will always be present? And number will not be in a valid team name?

Comment: `text.split('(')[0]`

Comment: It this format is consistent in that you are always trimming things off the end, you can sub out non-word characters at the end: `re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]+$', '', orig_str)`

Comment: Are you guaranteed there is pone and exactly one left-parenthesis, and that it's preceded by one space? And **must you use a regex**, rather than `string.split()` or `string.partition()` or `string.index`?

Comment: `"([a-zA-Z\s]*[a-zA-Z])\s*"` is another good regex solution that does not allow any characters other than spaces and letters, and does not give trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very simple method to accomplish this task would be to use plain o'l `split()`.

```
text = 'Atlanta Hawks (15)'
print(text.split(' (')[0])
```

output

```
Atlanta Hawks
```

Answer (score 0):

code：

```
x = 'Atlanta Hawks (15)'
print("".join([char for char in x if char.isalpha() or char == " "]).rstrip())
```

result:

```
Atlanta Hawks
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's consistently the last 'word' you need to remove:

```
s = 'Atlanta Hawks (15)'
' '.join(s.split()[:-1])
'Atlanta Hawks'
```

If you might not have a parenthesized number:

```
' '.join(s.split()[:-1]) if '(' in s else s
```

OR, stealing from Bob but correcting for the trailing space:

```
s.split(' (')[0]
```